# Creating variables that will be used as arguments affects the performance?

Tags: c#, performance, methods

Let's suppose I a method `abc(DataSet a, string b)` and I want to create an object of type DataSet and a variable of type string to use as arguments while calling abc, because I want to improve the code readability, would it use more computer resources thus affecting the performance (even if it's just a little)?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: It's possible the compiler may create variables anyway even if you don't explicitly (depending on the source of the arguments). I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Write the code both ways, measure the performance of both, and then you'll know the answer. *If you can't perceive a difference, what does it matter?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance will have negligible effect in this case.

However you will have to declare your variables in case you are performing some actions on your variables.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

//ds = .....

String str = "FooBar";

//str.Replace(......
```

and then pass them

```
abc(ds, str);
```

In programming its better to create a varible and pass the valuesb because readibility takes precedence over performance.